# for loop if else Break php

Tags: php

I'd like to add page like this :

```
foreach($list->result() as $row){
     if($no % 12 == 0 ) {
         // Add Page Break Here
         echo "<p>break</p>";
     }
     if($no % 6 == 0 ) {
         //// $pdf->Ln();
         echo "<br><br><br>";
     }

     echo $no;
     echo "<br>";
     $no++;
}
```

I want `if this data > 12` page break , if `this data < 12` not add page but `if data > 6` add more space

My problem is, it's always like this :

```
1
2
3
4
5
space
space
space
6
7
8
9
10
11
break
space
space
space
12
```

Comment: And what is the proiblem? (Except maybe wanting an `elseif` on your mod 6)

Comment: Ok, so what is the problem with this code. You have not actually asked a question

Comment: in start always until number 5 , i want if > 6 add space , if > 12 page break

Comment: I guess his problem is, that his code adds extra space after a pagebreak as well. You can solve this by replacing `$no % 6 == 0` with `$no % 12 == 6` by the way.

Comment: Put your breaks AFTER you echo your row content, and change `if($no % 6 == 0 )` to `elseif($no % 6 == 0 )` Because you want to prioritise the mod 12 and not call both.

Comment: Your question is downvoted quite heavily due to an unclear question and that you have not created a code that we can see the result on. We don't have `$list->result()`, create an array we can loop and reproduce the problem with.

Comment: iam try  if($no % 12 == 0 ) {
                /// Add Page Break Here
                echo "<p>break</p>";
            }
            elseif($no % 6 == 0 ){
                //// $pdf->Ln();
                echo "<br>space<br>space<br>space<br><br>";
            }
Not work

Comment: @DanuraAditya Do not explain what code you use, we can see that by ourselfs :-) Try to explain what exactly is not working instead. It is hard to understand your problem, if "*not work*" and "*It's always like this*" is how you describe it.

Comment: You can take 2 different count variable like lineBreakCount & pageBreakCount. Always reset both count variables, once used. As after every 12th row you need to switch on new page. Above will work for you.

Comment: just always until Number 5

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily fixed by:

```
foreach ($list->result() as $row)
{
    if ($row['SOMETHING??'] >= 12)
    {
        /// Add Page Break Here
        echo "<p>break</p>";
    }

    if ($row['SOMETHING??'] >= 6 && $row['SOMETHING??'] < 12)
    {
        //// $pdf->Ln();
        echo "<br><br><br>";
    }

    echo $no;
    echo "<br>";
    $no++;
}
```

Look carefully at the comparison operators which are being used.

**Documentation**:

> http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0):

You just need to re-arrange the order of what you are doing, you are outputting the breaks Before you output the line they relate to

```
foreach($list->result() as $row){

    echo $no;
    echo "<br>";

    if ($no % 12 == 0 ) {
         // Add Page Break Here
         echo "<p>break</p>";
    }
    if ($no % 6 == 0 ) {
         //// $pdf->Ln();
         echo "<br><br><br>";
    }
    $no++;
}
```

You may also need to stop the `%6` test doing something when the `%12` line will have done something like so

```
foreach($list->result() as $row){

    echo $no;
    echo "<br>";

    if ($no % 12 == 0 ) {
         // Add Page Break Here
         echo "<p>break</p>";
    }
    if ($no % 6 == 0 && $no % 12 != 0) {
         //// $pdf->Ln();
         echo "<br><br><br>";
    }
    $no++;
}
```